# Create GUID of Custom Format

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

.NET Allows to create GUID in pre-determined format..

I want to create it with my custom format..

Is it possible?how?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "custom format"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways, but what follows is a method I need to use a .NET Guid within PL/SQL editor (the bytes are in a different ordering):

```
  var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
  var oraBytes =
    new[]
      {
        bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0],
        bytes[5], bytes[4],
        bytes[7], bytes[6],
        bytes[8], bytes[9], bytes[10], bytes[11], bytes[12], 
        bytes[13], bytes[14], bytes[15]
      };

  Guid g = new Guid(oraBytes);
  return g.ToString("N").ToUpperInvariant();
```

It may give you some inspiration in laying out the bytes as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

from msdn :

> ```
> public Guid(
>     string g
> )
> ```
>
> g:
>
> Type: System..::.String A String that
>   contains a GUID in one of the
>   following formats ('d' represents a
>   hexadecimal digit whose case is
>   ignored): 32 contiguous digits:
>   dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
>   -or- Groups of 8, 4, 4, 4, and 12 digits with hyphens between the
>   groups. The entire GUID can optionally
>   be enclosed in matching braces or
>   parentheses:
>   dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd
>   -or- {dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd}
>   -or- (dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd)
>   -or- Groups of 8, 4, and 4 digits, and a subset of eight groups of 2 digits,
>   with each group prefixed by "0x" or
>   "0X", and separated by commas. The
>   entire GUID, as well as the subset, is
>   enclosed in matching braces:
>   {0xdddddddd, 0xdddd,
>   0xdddd,{0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd}}
>   All braces, commas, and "0x" prefixes
>   are required. All embedded spaces are
>   ignored. All leading zeroes in a group
>   are ignored. The digits shown in a
>   group are the maximum number of
>   meaningful digits that can appear in
>   that group. You can specify from 1 to
>   the number of digits shown for a
>   group. The specified digits are
>   assumed to be the low order digits of
>   the group.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to

1. create a custom GUID creator - with same return values as the standard GUID class - standard class with standard return values
2. create a custom GUID creator with custom return values - on the fly class and custom return values
3. Use standard GUID class with custom return values - Just the output value is custom here.

I am assuming you want the latter.

So here is is my attempt - note I've extended @flq's answer and added a helper method - the Random Number generator - and strung it to string version of the GUID this means it's both a GUID and in custom format.

```
public static string customGUIDGenerator(){
    Console.WriteLine("customGUIDGenerator() has been processed");
    var randomNumberForGuid = randomNumber();
    
    Guid g = new Guid();
    var bytes = g.ToByteArray();
    var oraBytes =
    new[]
      {
        bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0],
    bytes[5], bytes[4],
    bytes[7], bytes[6],
    bytes[8], bytes[9], bytes[10], bytes[11], bytes[12], 
    bytes[13], bytes[14], bytes[15]
      };
   Guid g2 = new Guid(oraBytes);
   return g2.ToString("N").ToUpperInvariant() + randomNumberForGuid;
}

public static string randomNumber(){
    // Instantiate random number generator using system-supplied value as seed.
    var rand = new Random();
    // Generate and display 1 random byte (integer) values.
    return rand.Next().ToString();
}
```